# No funciona usar bordes diferentes en una clase de design system para app

Tags: genexus, design, border

estoy intentando modificar los bordes de una tabla con una clase del DS de Gx. Al borde izquierdo le pongo un color diferente a los demas, y un tamaño diferente.
Cuando lo visualizo en el preview de WWPLUS se ve ok, pero cuando lo corro en el emulador de android se ve todo igual.

He intentado poner border-color rojo y luego el border-left-color en amarillo pero todo se ve del color rojo en la ejecucion (todos quedan iguales).

Tambien he intentado setear los colores por separado left, right, top, bottom pero no carga ni un solo color (no se ven los bordes).

```
.ResumenNumeroTablePanel2
    {

        font-family: $fonts.primary-font-family;
 

        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 8px;
        //border-color: #A0AFBB; // #7B91A3;
        border-left-color: #FFFF11;
        border-top-color: #FFFF11;
        border-bottom-color: #A0AFBB;
        border-right-color: #A0AFBB;
        border-bottom-width: 2px; 

    }
```

Saben a que se debe? Me podran ayudar?

Muchas gracias!

Mauricio